# How do i see a package definition in SSIS Catalog?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In my SQL Server instance we're using SSIS Catalog to store projects and packages. My team had an issue in the past couple of days of a SQL Agent job failing due a package referencing `/SSISDB/Jobs/ProjectName/Package.dtsx`. Well now that package doesn't exist. It is possible that it was renamed or deleted but it's an old package literally named Package.dtsx so we aren't sure what it even did.

I'm loading a back up of the msdb, master, and SSISDB databases from prior to this incident to see if I can pull the actual package definition, binary code, or something to tell me what it was doing. So my ultimate question is for a package stored in the SSIS Catalog, is there a way to pull the .dtsx file from somewhere so I can either recreate it (and name it better) or if it is not important anymore I can confirm we don't need it.

Comment: You can't decrypt the packages stored in the SSIS Catalog. That is intentional. You *can* open the project from the database, but you'll need to create a new instance with SSISDB set up, restore all the keys, etc, etc. Surely you have the SSIS Project in Source Control, so that should be your first point of call.

Comment: Projects, by default, also have versions enabled in SSISDB ([right click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkjas.png) the project in SSMS and select `Versions...`). Have you (temporarily) restored the deployed version to an older version to see if the package pops up? But still, the SSIS Project Source Control should be where you are looking.

Comment: @Larnu Unfortunately we don't have this package in the project directory where it should be. That's the only reason I'm entertaining the thought it could have been renamed accidentally. The problem with that is that all of the existing .dtsx files in the project directory show an april last modified date and the name change/deletion took place last week.

Comment: Source control monitors file name changes as well. I *assume* you're therefore implying you aren't sing source control. If so, it's time you do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the whole project with package of interest from SSIS Catalog with Visual Studio *Integration Project Import Wizard* project type. You need Admin access to SSISDB to be able to do this. Simply specify server and project you want to export.
If you want to do it in pure SQL without Visual Studio, the simplest approach to my HO would be the following:

1. Set a FileTables on some SQL DB.
2. Execute the following t-SQL statements:

   ```
   DECLARE @t table
   (
   v varbinary(max)
   )

   INSERT @t
   EXEC SSISDB.catalog.get_project '<Project Path>','<Project Name>'
   INSERT [dbo].[MyFileTable] (name,file_stream)
   SELECT 'ExportedProject.ispac',v
   FROM @t
   ```

This will yield an `ExportedProject.ispac` file in FileTable folder.

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully the project directory was stored on a network drive which has 2 daily archived copies stored for a few weeks. I was able to go into an archived copy of the project folder into `Path\ProjectFolder\obj\Developement\` and there I found the Package.dtsx file with a Date Modified proving that it was the package I was looking for.

The true problem I had was trying to recover a lost pacakge, the solution to which is above (archived copy of directory). But Ferdipux answered the question that was asked in how to extract an SSIS Catalog project.